# How To Change Property Value Which Was Get By Reflection C#

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, reflection

I have a dll which has a button class. it looks something like that:

```
internal class CoolButton12345: UserControl
{
  all fields, properties and methods...
  public Image Image{get;set;}
}
```

I'm trying to change this button property value to my own.

```
dynamic playButton = typeof (FooDll).Assembly.GetType("ClassWhichHasThisButton")
                .GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "playButton").GetValue(FooInstance.Controls[0]);
playButton.Image = (Image)pauseBitmap;
```

But I'm getting this error

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll

Why my method is wrong?
Please tell me can I do something like that or not?
If I can please help to find the way how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dynamic playButton = FooInstance.playButton;

playButton.Image = (Image)pauseBitmap;
```

Comment: Could You please add some code how could I do something like that?

Comment: It is ok, but I need to set value to Image property of playButton, not to playButton.

Comment: then you'd need to refelect `Image` property of that object.

Comment: I can get instance just from Controls array. So it has UserControl type.

Comment: I get Exception: "'System.Windows.Forms.UserControl' does not contain a definition for 'Image'"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78426/discussion-between-oleg-dobra-and-t-mckeown).

Comment: do into debugger, `playButton` instance is what type?

Comment: It is dynamic{CoolButton12345} type. Could you please write to the chat?

Comment: Yeah as i written before

Comment: Can you help me to reflect Image property